# AddSubView is not working in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I need to place my labels and other objects into a scrollable view. But it doesn't add my 2 labels, I only get a white background everytime I run my program

```
- (void) initLayout:(CGRect)frame
{
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIFont *customFont  = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:40.0]; //custom font

scrollView                  = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self addSubview:scrollView];

oponent                 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
oponent.font            = customFont;
oponent.textColor       = [UIColor blackColor];
oponent.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
oponent.text            = @"TEST";
[scrollView addSubview:oponent];

proponent                 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
proponent.font            = customFont;
proponent.textColor       = [UIColor blackColor];
proponent.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
proponent.text            = @"TRY";
[scrollView addSubview:proponent];


}
```

Comment: You need to set a frame for each label without that it will be not visible in scrollview.

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting frames for proponent and opponent labels. Set their frames and also set content size for scrollview. You can also check by setting some border colors to your labels.

To check if your scrollview is working add UIScrollViewDelegate in your header file and then use the delegate methods.

```
scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Add the following delegate method and use breakpoint to check if it is called

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView

{

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Now, how can I check if the scrollview is working?

Comment: Did you set UIScrollViewDelegate in header of your class like        @interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate> ?

Answer (score 1):

You Haven't set frame to label

```
oponent                 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

proponent                 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

set frames

```
CGRect labelframe           // Customize according to your need

oponent  = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelframe];  // missing 

proponent = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelframe];  // missing
```